# Angular 12+ How to load component with Name (string) or selector (string)

Tags: angular

I have created Angular 12 project with desired output where component name I am passing in div tag and automatically it get rendered. Please find stackblitz link below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejxekn

If "Enable Ivy" option is checked (image given below) then its throwing error.
[image]

I understand that `ComponentFactoryResolver` is deprecated but how to apply same above logic to newer version not able to find by googling. I tried to load dynamic component in Angular 14 Application (below is the link) but not with the component string which I want.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqvwmd

Please help!.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the resolver you don't need it at this version.

Your Code:

```js
import {
  Component,
  VERSION,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(
    private cvRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  async loadLazy1() {
    this.cvRef.clear();
    //const { Lazy1 } = await import('./lazy-comp1/lazy-comp1.component')

    const { LazyComp1Component } = await import(
      './lazy-comp1/lazy-comp1.component'
    );
    this.cvRef.createComponent(LazyComp1Component);
  }
}
```

You can also do:

```js
import {
  Component,
  VERSION,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { LazyComp1Component } from './lazy-comp1/lazy-comp1.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor(
    private cvRef: ViewContainerRef,
  ) {}

  async loadLazy1() {
    this.cvRef.clear();
    this.cvRef.createComponent(LazyComp1Component);
  }
}
```

Comment: Above example running OK as given in stackblitz link. Thing is I must right down const { LazyComp1Component } which is not in string binding.

Comment: @Snehal you can implement this with out the `const`, or you have specific use case if you can give more details about what you try to achieve

Comment: If you check first link in app.component.ts file - template tag. I mention <div ctrl-factory comp="MyComponent1"></div> component in string format. It will find that component and load in to the div area. That link is workable if you check. Same thing I want to do in latest code.